Mod 2 Intersection Number of $f\times f$
Let be $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ such $m=2n$ and $n\geq 1$, and $f:\mathbb{S}^{n}\to \mathbb{S}^{m}$ a differentiable function.
Show that $I_{2}(f,f)=0$.
Here:
$$\triangle_{~\mathbb{S}^{m}}:=\{(s,s)\mid s\in \mathbb{S}^{m}\}\subseteq \mathbb{S}^{m}\times \mathbb{S}^{m}$$
and $I_{2}(f,f)=I_{2}(f\times f,\triangle_{~\mathbb{S}^{m}})$ the mod 2 intersection number of:
$$f\times f:\mathbb{S}^{n}\times \mathbb{S}^{n}\to \mathbb{S}^{m}\times \mathbb{S}^{m}~;~(f\times f)(s,t)=(f(s),f(t))$$
I wanted to use Boundary theorem of Guillemin/Pollack book of Differential Topology by noticing $\mathbb{S}^{m}\times \mathbb{S}^{m}$ is simply connected, but $\mathbb{D}^{m}\times \mathbb{D}^{m}$ with $\mathbb{D}^{m}$ the closed unit disc is not a manifold with boundary. So I have to find $g$ some homotopy of $f\times f$ transversal to the diagonal, in order to find $g^{-1}[\triangle_{\mathbb{S}^{m}}]=\varnothing$. Any help or suggestion?

First, the boundary of $\Bbb D^k$ is $\Bbb S^{k-1}$.
Second, $\Bbb D\times\Bbb D$ is not a manifold with boundary.
Third, the boundary theorem only applies if $f$ extends to a map of $\Bbb D$ in the first place.

Yes, I already explain why I abandoned that idea.

Not really. What manifold with boundary actually has $\Bbb S\times\Bbb S$ has its boundary? But you still need to understand my other points. What other ideas might you try? Where did you find this problem? It is not in G&P.

Well $\partial(\mathbb{D}^{2}\times \mathbb{S}^{1})=\mathbb{S}^{1}\times\mathbb{S}^{1}$. This is just a problem of my homework, don't know where it comes. I don't know what else do, that's why I post this question, I'm just thinking in a function $g$ as I describe it.

$\partial (A \times B) = \partial A \times B \cup A\times \partial B$ so you can take $\mathbb D^{m+1} \times \mathbb S^m$ for the rest I did not look into it

What do you know about intersection numbers $I_2(f,Z)$ when $Z\subset \Bbb S^m$?
